# Can't get card flip animation to work

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation, flip

I am working on a game that involves cards (ImageViews) with a labels over them showing a random word. I would like the intro to start with a ImageView showing the back of a card then flipping to the front with a different image and the label. I am working with the code below, but It seems to just flip to the same side. How do I incorporate a different image for the front and include the label with the word?

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self.imageView6, duration: 1.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, animations:{
},
completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The views you want to transition between should be contained within another view, see the following hierarchy:

[image: View Hierarchy]

The transition should then be applied to the "Transition View":

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self.transitionView, duration: 1.5, options: .TransitionFlipFromRight, animations:{

    self.frontImageView.hidden = self.showingImage;
    self.behindView.hidden = !self.showingImage;

}) { (complete) -> Void in
    self.showingImage = !self.showingImage
}
```

`self.showingImage` is a simple `Bool` instance variable to keep track of which view is currently being shown.

Comment: This worked extremely well and was very easy to understand. Thank you!